# Cron job with cron scheduler is not working - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron-task

This is the code I have used to schedule CRON job.

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_every_ten_seconds' );
function isa_add_every_ten_seconds( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_ten_seconds'] = array(
            'interval'  => 10,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 10 seconds', 'sometext' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}

// Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'isa_add_every_ten_seconds' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_ten_seconds', 'isa_add_every_ten_seconds' );
}

// Hook into that action that'll fire every three minutes
add_action( 'isa_add_every_ten_seconds', 'every_ten_seconds_function_func' );
function every_ten_seconds_function_func() {
    update_page();
}
```

I have checked this in local server and also in real server. No change. Whats wrong in the code???

Comment: You're trying to actually schedule a cronjob? Not the WordPress implementation but the native Linux daemon? If so, there's no 10 second interval possible. Smallest unit is minutes

Comment: But at this link `https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/understanding-wp-cron-scheduling/` they showed `interval` for 5 seconds.

Comment: Like I said, if you're trying to set a cron in the native Linux daemon, you're constrained by the 1 minute minimum interval. Didnt say so for wordpress. Also keep in mind that the WordPress implementation is not a daemon per se and needs the WP core to run so the scheduled actions are executed. If you are testing on a WP instance that's not receiving any traffic nothing will ever happen.

Comment: It's not working. Is the code wrong or I have placed the code in a wrong place

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I have checked every answer in StackOverflow. Nothing wrong in the code but still it's not working.